# Is there a way I can keep my plant cuttings humid indoors?

Tags: trees, hydroponic

I just started trying to root cuttings in a hydroponic cloning system I built. Is there any way I can keep my cutting humid indoors? Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify your question.

Comment: Oh sorry. I wanted to know how I can keep my cutting humid indoors. I read that in order for it to root, it needs to be humid. How can I achieve that indoors.

Comment: Can you add a picture of your system, several different ones exists. The point of the system is to keep roots constantly fed with the right amount of water and nutrients controlled by a timer/computer... hence why I don’t understand the question

Comment: You can use a humidifier and controller

Comment: please add more details about what type of system, the type of plant and other information that could help people give you a better answer.

Comment: Well, they're trees, whatever kinds they are (according to the tag). A humidity dome may help.

Answer (score 2):

For hydroponics, it is recommended that you start your plants in a separate container and then transplant them into your system. The best method for keeping them humid is to place the plant itself in a plastic bag and use rooting hormone on the stem to start the plant. This keeps the hormone in one place and prevents the cutting from drying out. Another method is running root hormone through your hydroponics system and rooting all of your cuttings at once the cutting will stay humid because it is a hydroponic system and the water evaporating keeps the plant green. This gets expensive tho and is recommended for industrial applications. Then the third method depends on the type of plant you are growing because there are some tricks there too.

Answer (score 2):

When new cuttings are inserted into a hydroponic system for cloning, they can look fine for a few days and then start to wilt even though they are immersed in nutrient solution. This wilting can be caused by too strong a nutrient solution. Cloned plants don't have a root system yet, so they lack a way to regulate water and nutrient uptake. Water is a clone's primary need until roots form. Water is required for circulation and structure. When root buds form, gradually increase nutrients to normal levels. I start my tomato clones in mason jars with the node immediately above the cut immersed in about 1" of very dilute nutrient solution (no deeper). Once roots start to grow, I move the clone in with the other plants. Ambient humidity is about 50-60%, so I do not use a humidifier.